# Flutter input widget with multiple options (monthly/annual/currency/percentage)

Tags: dart, flutter

I currently have the following code to build this widget:

[image]

```dart
                        MonthlyAnnualSection(
                          title: 'Tax Expense',
                          onValueChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly =
                                  value == 'm';
                            });
                          },
                          children: [
                            Panel(
                              key: Key(
                                  'taxes${defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly ? 'Monthly' : 'Annual'}'),
                              title: ' Taxes',
                              isPercentage:
                                  defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesAsPercentage,
                              onIsPercentageChanged: (val) {
                                setState(() {
                                  defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesAsPercentage = val;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                                  if (defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesAsPercentage)
                                    PercentageTextField(
                                      value: defaults
                                              .shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly
                                          ? defaults.taxesPercent
                                          : defaults.taxesPercent * 12,
                                      placeholder:
                                          'example: ${(defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly ? defaults.taxesPercent : defaults.taxesPercent * 12).toPercentage()}',
                                      onValueChanged: (val) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          defaults.taxesPercent = defaults
                                                  .shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly
                                              ? val
                                              : val / 12;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  if (!defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesAsPercentage)
                                    CurrencyTextField(
                                      value: defaults
                                              .shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly
                                          ? defaults.taxes
                                          : defaults.taxes * 12,
                                      placeholder:
                                          'example: ${(defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly ? defaults.taxes : defaults.taxes * 12).toCurrency()}',
                                      onValueChanged: (val) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          defaults.taxes = defaults
                                                  .shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly
                                              ? val
                                              : val / 12;
                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

and this is the class where that `defaults` is coming from:

```dart
class Defaults {
  bool shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly;
  bool shouldDisplayTaxesAsPercentage;
  double taxes;
  double taxesPercent;
  bool shouldDisplayManagementExpensesMonthly;
  bool shouldDisplayManagementAsPercentage;
  double management;
  double managementPercent;
}
```

The problem as you can see, is that it takes a lot of ternary methods plus if I want to make a second similar widget below it (to use it for the management expenses, instead of tax) it takes a LOT of repeating.

Ideally I would love to just have something like this:

```
Section(
   title: 'Tax Expense',
   subtitle: ' Taxes',
   value: defaults.taxes,
   percent: defaults.taxesPercent,
   shouldDisplayMonthly: defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly,
   shouldDisplayAsPercentage: defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesAsPercentage,
),
Section(
   title: 'Management Expense',
   subtitle: ' Management',
   value: defaults.management,
   percent: defaults.managementPercent,
   shouldDisplayMonthly: defaults.shouldDisplayManagementExpensesMonthly,
   shouldDisplayAsPercentage: defaults.shouldDisplayManagementsAsPercentage,
),
```

And then it would be sorted... but apparently Dart doesn't support reflection, so I'm not sure how I could do that?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that possible you can make class function or a separate stateless widget for code reusability.

```
class Section extends StatelessWidget {
  const Section(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      required this.subtitle,
      required this.value,
      required this.percent,
      required this.shouldDisplayMonthly,
      required this.shouldDisplayAsPercentage,
      required this.onTexesOrManagementValueChange,
      required this.onPercentageValueChanged,
      required this.onMonthlyAnnuallySelectionChange,
      required this.onIsPercentageChanged});

  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final double value;
  final double percent;
  final bool shouldDisplayMonthly;
  final bool shouldDisplayAsPercentage;
  final void Function() onTexesOrManagementValueChange;
  final void Function() onPercentageValueChanged;
  final void Function() onMonthlyAnnuallySelectionChange;
  final void Function(dynamic) onIsPercentageChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MonthlyAnnualSection(
      title: title,
      onValueChanged: onMonthlyAnnuallySelectionChange,
      children: [
        Panel(
          key: Key('$subtitle${shouldDisplayMonthly ? 'Monthly' : 'Annual'}'),
          title: subtitle,
          isPercentage: shouldDisplayAsPercentage,
          onIsPercentageChanged: onIsPercentageChanged,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              if (shouldDisplayAsPercentage)
                PercentageTextField(
                    value: shouldDisplayMonthly ? percent : percent * 12,
                    placeholder:
                        'example: ${(shouldDisplayMonthly ? percent : percent * 12).toPercentage()}',
                    onValueChanged: onPercentageValueChanged),
              if (!shouldDisplayAsPercentage)
                CurrencyTextField(
                  value: shouldDisplayMonthly ? value : value * 12,
                  placeholder:
                      'example: ${(shouldDisplayMonthly ? value : value * 12).toCurrency()}',
                  onValueChanged: onTexesOrManagementValueChange,
                ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But in flutter making a `StatelessWidget` is good practice, and as it is going to be a `StatelessWidget` you need to do the operation like change values in the class where you are using it.

Like for this above code you need to call it like:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Section(
        title: 'Tax Expense',
        subtitle: ' Taxes',
        value: defaults.taxes,
        percent: defaults.taxesPercent,
        shouldDisplayMonthly: defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly,
        shouldDisplayAsPercentage: defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesAsPercentage,
        onIsPercentageChanged: (val) =>
            setState(() => defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesAsPercentage = val),
        onMonthlyAnnuallySelectionChange: (value) => setState(
            () => defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly = value == 'm'),
        onPercentageValueChanged: (val) => setState(() =>
            defaults.taxesPercent =
                defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly ? val : val / 12),
        onTexesOrManagementValueChange: (val) => setState(() => defaults.taxes =
            defaults.shouldDisplayTaxesExpensesMonthly ? val : val / 12),
      ),
    );
```